# MongDB count query not using Index

Tags: mongodb

I've seen this question being asked a number of times, and it ends up being an order issue with compound indexes, but my issue is a little simpler.

I have very large Database with 250M+ documents, and I'm trying to sanitize some of the older documents, where we have a string field that contains a timestamp. I'm trying to match / count documents that do NOT match the present format, using regular expression.

**Query**:

```
{ "timestamp": { "$not" : /^[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+ [0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+$/ } }
```

I have a non compound index on the timestamp field though.

**Index**

```
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "timestamp" : 1
    },
    "name" : "timestamp",
    "ns" : "weblogsdb.weblogsCol",
    "dropDups" : false,
    "background" : false
}
```

Now, I can't run the explain query for a deeper look, since that itself also runs hours, but from the db.currentOps() call, I can see it's using COLLSCAN:

**db.currentOp()**

```
    {
        "opid": 121436812,
        "active": true,
        "secs_running": 27,
        "microsecs_running": NumberLong(27006658),
        "op": "query",
        "ns": "weblogsdb.weblogsCol",
        "query": {
            "count": "weblogsCol",
            "fields": {
                "timestamp": 1
            },
            "query": {
                "timestamp": {
                    "$not": /^[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+ [0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+$/
                }
            }
        },
        "planSummary": "COLLSCAN",
        "client": "127.0.0.1:56796",
        "desc": "conn150511",
        "threadId": "0x7d5337d13700",
        "connectionId": 150511,
        "locks": {
            "^v5_live_weblogs": "R"
        },
        "waitingForLock": true,
        "numYields": 14655,
        "lockStats": {
            "timeLockedMicros": {
                "r": NumberLong(42127960),
                "w": NumberLong(0)
            },
            "timeAcquiringMicros": {
                "r": NumberLong(951332),
                "w": NumberLong(0)
            }
        }
    }
```

I've checked the MongoDB Documentation regarding regular expression matches, and it uses indexes for the scan, but there isn't much information about the "$not" operator, and the impact of that on the query.

https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.2/reference/operator/query/regex/

Any suggestions of what I can do to either improve the query performance, and an explanation about where I'm going wrong would be greatly appreciated.

It may be worth nothing that I am using an older version of mongoDB (v2.6.12)

Comment: I assume we are talking of a sharded cluster?

Comment: I would have loved to put 250M documents into a sharded cluster, but sadly I only have the resources for a Master / Slave / Arbiter Replica set. The data is mostly for BI / Logs so not mission critical enough to validate the costs of a sharded cluster.